# Check if three fourth part of polygon lies inside another polygon using shapely/any other method

Tags: python, shapely

Currently, I check if my polygon lies within another polygon using polya.contains(polyb)

However, it is not necessary my polygon polyb lies completely inside polya. Is there a built-in method to check if three-fourth of the polygon is inside polya?

Comment: Calculate the intersection and calculate the area percentage of polyb?

Comment: Good idea, I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, posting my answer here if anyone else might need it. I used the hint given by Mr. T, the solution was extremely simple.
I check if the overlapping area is within a certain threshold. It is also similar to the concept of IOU in Computer Vision.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

threshold = 0.75
polygon_intersection = polya.intersection(polyb).area
area = polygon_intersection / polyb.area 
if area > threshold:
    #do something
```